# netbeans jboss client connection failure

Tags: jboss, connection, ejb, client

I just started to learn EJB by going thru a tutorial.  I started a JBoss server on localhost.  The server started ok, listening on port `4447`, `9999` & `8080`.

But I keep getting an error running a client. The error message is:

`Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099`.

I tried to change the port number to `4447`, `9999`,`8080`, but still keep getting the same error message.

JBoss version jboss-as-7.1.0.Final.  NetBeans 7.4. JDK 1.6. I already spent hours on it, but still was not able fix it.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is using the old jnp-protocol for JNDI-lookup (see jndi.properties or code). This is not supported in jboss7. You need to go along the lines of https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI